# Javascript código de redirecionamento URL

Tags: javascript

eu preciso desenvolver um código em javascript que não está funcionando.

Minha necessidade é a seguinte:

Quando o usuário acessar determinada página, eu gostaria de complementar a URL com alguns parâmetros, exemplo:

Se o dominio for xxx.com.br/index.php, redirecione ele para xxx.com.br/index.php&variavel=1

Lembrando que ele pode entrar também em um subdiretorio, exemplo:

xxx.com.br/pasta/index.php, deve adicionar também xxx.com.br/pasta/index.php&variavel=1

Basicamente, se o dominio coicidir, ele adiciona uma variavel no final.

Detalhe importante, fiz isso e o mesmo ficou em loop, porque ao redirecionar ele identifica o dominio da mesma maneira, portanto, se o dominio bater, deve ter outra verificação pra ver se já não existe o parametro na URL.

Comment: Tentou `document.URL` ??

Answer (score 4):

Adicionar somente `&variavel=1` ao URL parece-me errado, nesse caso devia usar a "query" string que começa com `?`. Ou seja usando [`location.search`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.location).

Assim pode ter o seguinte script em todas as páginas que precisar dessa funcionalidade:

```
location.search = location.search || '?variavel=1';
```

Combinando isto com o `location.hostname` pode verificar se o dominio é correto pois o `location.hostname` dá exatamente essa informação.

Assim o seu código completo poderia ser:

```
if (location.hostname == 'xxx.com.br') location.search = location.search || '?variavel=1';
```

Comment: eu não sabia do `location.search`, obrigado!

Answer (score 2):

Segue uma função que já testa se o parâmetro existe no URL original, e caso não exista, acrescenta.

Esta função está preparada para os casos em que já existem outros valores especificados, e os mantém como estavam:

```
function setDefaultParameter( url, parameter, value ) {    
  if ( ("&"+url.split("?")[1]+"=").indexOf("&"+parameter+"=") < 0 ) {
    url += (url.split("?")[1]?'&':'?') + parameter + '=' + value;
  }
  return url;
}
```

Basta chamar desta forma para setar todos os parâmetros que quiser:

```
novoUrl = setDefaultParameter( window.location.href, 'modelo', '1'    );
novoUrl = setDefaultParameter( novoUrl             , 'ano'   , '2014' );

// Redireciona só se mudou algo:
if ( novoUrl != window.location.href ) {
  window.location = novoUrl ;
}
```

### Demonstração:

```js
function setDefaultParameter( url, parameter, value ) {    
  if ( ("&"+url.split("?")[1]+"=").indexOf("&"+parameter+"=") < 0 ) {
    url += (url.split("?")[1]?'&':'?') + parameter + '=' + value;
  }
  return url;
}

// Sem nenhum parametro
var url = 'http://example.com';
url = setDefaultParameter( url, 'modelo', '1' );
url = setDefaultParameter( url, 'ano', '2014' );
document.body.innerHTML += url + '<br>';

// com parametro já existente
url = 'http://example.com?cor=azul';
url = setDefaultParameter( url, 'modelo', '1' );
url = setDefaultParameter( url, 'ano', '2014' );
document.body.innerHTML += url + '<br>';

// com um dos parâmetros já especificado sendo preservado
url = 'http://example.com?ano=1998';
url = setDefaultParameter( url, 'modelo', '1' );
url = setDefaultParameter( url, 'ano', '2014' );
document.body.innerHTML += url + '<br>';
```

Comment: @FabioVieira Se achar necessário, posto uma variante que sobreescreve o parâmetro, mesmo se ele já existir.

Answer (score 1):

Dessa forma você consegue pegar toda a URL e fazer as verificações nescessárias:

```
switch(document.URL){
    case 'http://www.meudominio.com/index.html': 
        location.href='/index.html?parametros' 
        break;
    case 'http://www.meudominio.com/outra.html': 
        location.href='/outra.html?parametros' 
        break;   
  }
}
alert(document.URL); //apenas para ver o que tem em document.URL
```

Comment: Mas onde está validando o dominio?

Comment: Basta colocar no `case 'minhaURL'`... valida toda a URL de uma vez

Answer (score 0):

Basta verificar e validar o host e a url(href) do usuário, de forma que deve adicionar se dominio for igual a `x` porém não adicionar se já houver:

```
function validaDominio(dominioX){
  var host         = document.location.host;
  var addr         = document.location.href;
  var dominioEnd   = host.indexOf('.');
  var dominio      = host.substring(0, dominioEnd);

  if (dominio == dominioX && (addr.indexOf('&variavel') == -1))
    document.location.href = document.location.href + '&variavel=1';
}
```

E aí basta adicionar o parâmetro `onload=validaDominio('xxx')` no `<body>` das páginas que você quer verificar, ficando:

```
<body onload=validaDominio('xxx') >
```

Comment: `dominio == dominio` ? Algo errado não? rsrsr

Comment: agora está certo, obrigado @AntonyAlkmim